# Modify inbook citation when author is same as bookauthor

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have `inbook` entry where `author` is the same as `bookauthor`. By default a `bookauthor` is omitted in citations in such a case. It can be changed by

```
\renewbibmacro*{bybookauthor}{%
\printnames{bookauthor}
}
```

But now we have the same name printed twice. How can I enable `idemtracker` inside of `inbook` entry?
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@inbook{mybook,
  author={Done, John},
  bookauthor={Done, John},
  title={Chapter title},    
  booktitle={Main book title},
crossref={mainbook},
}
\end{filecontents}

\renewbibmacro*{bybookauthor}{%
 \printnames{bookauthor}
}

\begin{document}
\cite{mybook}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: result]

Expected result:
[image: expectation]

**UPD:**

I've found partial solution:

```
\renewbibmacro*{bybookauthor}{%
  \ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}
    {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
      \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
    {\printnames{bookauthor}}
```

}
Or even

```
\renewbibmacro*{bybookauthor}{%
  \ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
    {\printnames{bookauthor}}}
```

results:
[image: result2]
But now the problem is the dot between *idem* and `booktitle`. A comma is expected.

Comment: It is usually not expected for an `@inbook`, but might be possible for `@suppbook` (which is aliased to `@inbook`) or in very specific situations that `author` and `bookauthor` are not equal (so you wouldn't get an *idem*), do you want the comma in that case as well or would you want a period?

Comment: I thought `@suppbook` is rather preferred when citing the preface, afterwords etc. In my case it is totally independent chapter. The book himself is a kind of collection of an independent articles (chapters) written by the same author and published as a book. There must be a comma in this place, even if I use some other delimiter between author, title, publisher etc.

Comment: Sure, the thing is that I wanted to know what would happen if `author` and `bookauthor` are not the same (and you get no *idem* but the full `bookauthor`), do you want a comma in that case as well or a period? (The comment about `@suppbook` was just to emphasise that this is not a purely academic question, but a real possibility.)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood you. In that case (`author` and `bookauthor` are not equal) a default blocks delimiter (`\newunitpunct`) must be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the delimiter right is a bit tricky, because the punctuation tracker usually prints the last punctuation it gets and the drivers add `\newunitpunct` after executing the `bookauthor` bibmacro. We can use `\printunit` instead of the normal `\setunit` to work around that.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{bybookauthor}{%
  \ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}
    {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
     \printunit{\addcomma\space}}
    {\printnames{bookauthor}}}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{mybook,
  author     = {Done, John},
  bookauthor = {Done, John},
  title      = {Chapter title},
  booktitle  = {Main book title},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{mybook}
\end{document}
```

[image: John Done. “Chapter title”. In: idem, Main book title]

Comment: Great as always. Many thanks!